# How to run vulkan example code in windows by mingw-w64?

Tags: c++, g++, glfw, vulkan, mingw-w64

everyone.
I begin learn vulkan sdk programing in my window laptop rencently. I download the VulkanSDK-1.2.162.0, x86_64-8.1.0-release-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0 and glfw-3.3.2.bin.WIN64, Unzip them and set the windows path, all is done and test resualt show in cmd like this:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>g++ --version
g++ (x86_64-win32-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

```
C:\Users\Administrator>vulkaninfo
==========
VULKANINFO
==========

Vulkan Instance Version: 1.2.154


Instance Extensions: count = 11
===============================
        VK_EXT_debug_report                    : extension revision 9
        VK_EXT_debug_utils                     : extension revision 2
        VK_EXT_swapchain_colorspace            : extension revision 4
......
......
......
```

I am a beginner of c/c++ programing, in my basic understanding of the c/c++ complier workflow, it need the header file path and library path. So, I try to run vulkan's official [cpp code](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/code/00_base_code.cpp) in my machine with g++ command like this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 vlkantest.cpp -I D:\\Other\\Vulkan\\SDK_ROOT\\1.2.162.0\\Include -I D:\\Other\\mingw64\\include -I D:\\Other\\glfw-3.3.2.bin.WIN64\\include -L D:\\Other\\Vulkan\\SDK_ROOT\\1.2.162.0\\Lib -L D:\\Other\\mingw64\\lib -L D:\\Other\\glfw-3.3.2.bin.WIN64\\lib-mingw-w64
```

But, I just get the result like this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 vlkantest.cpp -I D:\\Other\\Vulkan\\SDK_ROOT\\1.2.162.0\\Include -I D:\\Other\\mingw64\\include -I D:\\Other\\glfw-3.3.2.bin.WIN64\\include -L D:\\Other\\Vulkan\\SDK_ROOT\\1.2.162.0\\Lib -L D:\\Other\\mingw64\\lib -L D:\\Other\\glfw-3.3.2.bin.WIN64\\lib-mingw-w64
C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccdv6xfT.o:vlkantest.cpp:(.text$_ZN24HelloTriangleApplication10initWindowEv[_ZN24HelloTriangleApplication10initWindowEv]+0xd): undefined reference to `glfwInit'
C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccdv6xfT.o:vlkantest.cpp:(.text$_ZN24HelloTriangleApplication10initWindowEv[_ZN24HelloTriangleApplication10initWindowEv]+0x1c): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccdv6xfT.o:vlkantest.cpp:(.text$_ZN24HelloTriangleApplication10initWindowEv[_ZN24HelloTriangleApplication10initWindowEv]+0x2b): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccdv6xfT.o:vlkantest.cpp:(.text$_ZN24HelloTriangleApplication10initWindowEv[_ZN24HelloTriangleApplication10initWindowEv]+0x50): undefined reference to `glfwCreateWindow'
C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccdv6xfT.o:vlkantest.cpp:(.text$_ZN24HelloTriangleApplication8mainLoopEv[_ZN24HelloTriangleApplication8mainLoopEv]+0x17): undefined reference to `glfwWindowShouldClose'
C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccdv6xfT.o:vlkantest.cpp:(.text$_ZN24HelloTriangleApplication8mainLoopEv[_ZN24HelloTriangleApplication8mainLoopEv]+0x25): undefined reference to `glfwPollEvents'
C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccdv6xfT.o:vlkantest.cpp:(.text$_ZN24HelloTriangleApplication7cleanupEv[_ZN24HelloTriangleApplication7cleanupEv]+0x17): undefined reference to `glfwDestroyWindow'
C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccdv6xfT.o:vlkantest.cpp:(.text$_ZN24HelloTriangleApplication7cleanupEv[_ZN24HelloTriangleApplication7cleanupEv]+0x1c): undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I think I miss some args for g++, Is anyone can point out my mistake in above g++ command? or just simply explain how this example code run in windows by mingw-w64?
Thank a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have specified library folders but not actually linked the libraries. Have you tried adding `-lglfw3 -lvulkan-1` to your compile command?

Comment: I delete libglfw3.a, libglfw3dll.a under the glfw-3.3.2.bin.WIN64\lib-mingw-w64, just remain gflw3.dll, and adding -lglfw3 -lvulkan args in g++ command, it work~ thanks.